# Full path of a docker image file required in NGINX repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am new to DOCKER and working with AWS. I am supposed to create a CONTAINER and add it to a ECS CLUSTER. It is asking for 2 parameters:

1. IMAGE
   Which should have a format `repository-url/image:tag`. I am not able to mention the FULL PATH of the file within NGINX repository. Please select a very simple file so that running it as a TASK on a EC2 CONTAINER should be easy.
2. PORT MAPPINGS and CONTAINER PORT
   I am confused with what PORT to give. Is it 80? Regarding HOST, I can give the PUBLIC IPV4 ADDRESS of 4 EC2 CONTAINERS present within the CLUSTER.

Answer (score 0):

See "[Couchbase Docker Container on Amazon ECS](http://blog.arungupta.me/amazon-ec2-container-service-docker-couchbase/)" as an example:

> In ECS, Docker workloads are defined as tasks. A task can contain multiple containers. All containers for a task are co-located on the same machine.

[image: http://blog.arungupta.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/aws-ec2-container-2-1024x795.png]

> ... 
>   And finally the port mappings (`-p` on Docker CLI). Port 8091 is needed for Couchbase administration.

It is certainly 80 for your NGiNX, and you can map it to any port you want (typically 80) on your host.

Comment: Thanks Von. However, I need to know if any DOCKER IMAGE file is pushed in ECR / DOCKER HUB, how to get it's FULL PATH (i.e., starting from registry, etc. If you could post a few screenshots, it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Von, I have 2 more questions:
(1) I am confused between JOB DEFINITION and TASK DEFINITION. If we mention the COMMAND and ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in JOB DEFINITION page, does it get OVERRIDDEN by the parameters in the SUBMIT JOBS page? 
(2) If we mention the COMMAND / ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES in JOB DEFINITION page, do we need to mention the SAME in the TASK DEFINITION page as well?

Comment: @Sudip Job (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/jobs.html) is the unit of work executed by AWS Batch. Task (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html) is how you run jobs like batch jobs. It is best to ask a new question with screenshot illustrating your use case.